# Answering current meteorological events that are evolving

Tags: discussion

What would be the best strategy to answer meteorological events that are still evolving and whose data is still being gathered and analysed ?

Recently this question was asked - [Two severe cyclones connected by a monsoonal trough](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/4426/two-severe-cyclones-connected-by-a-monsoonal-trough)

One way to answer this would be to look at any past events that are similar or identical to those.

Another way is to run a simulation ourselves (if we have the infrastructure) and then present our results. But will the community accept results that are not peer reviewed ?

The last approach is to present a guess that could be proven wrong later.

Comment: The question example can be answered by using similar examples of events, and good ol' research

Comment: Would our own simulations be valid answers ?

Comment: If it shows the phenomena being asked about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Information about similar past events would be best, but that does not mean that results from simulations done by our members should not be allowed or would not produce a useful or meaning answer.

One thing I would encourage is that anyone who provides an answer based on a simulation they've done to also give as much detail about setting up the simulation, the data used, the software used and what assumptions were made.

Comment: Precisely the kind of answer that I am looking for in such a question.